# Grpc Server Can not Overload method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, grpc, .net-5

I want to build a very simple client and server application in Grpc C#
for first time I built it successfully but when I want to build an other Service got error 'C0115 no suitable method found for override '

Here is My Code :

```
ServiceHubService.cs in Services Folder

`
namespace NetPlus.Server.Core

{
    public class ServerHubService : ServereHub.ServereHubBase
   
 {
      
 
private readonly ILogger<ServerHubService> _logger;

       
 public ServerHubService(ILogger<ServerHubService> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public override Task<ActionResult> GetActionResult(ActionRequest request, ServerCallContext context)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(new ActionResult
            {
                ActionResultType = "Test"
            });
        }
    }
    
}`
```

ProtoBuffer File :

```
  syntax = "proto3";
        
        option csharp_namespace = "NetPlus.Server.Core";
        
        package server;
        
        
        service ServereHub  {
        
        rpc ActionManager (ActionRequest) returns (ActionResult);
        
        }
        
        message ActionRequest {
            string ActionType = 1;
        }
        
        message ActionResult {
            string ActionResultType = 1;
        }
```

what is wrong?

I have using

visual studio 16.10.0
net 6.0 preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your proto file, you've defined

```
rpc ActionManager (ActionRequest) returns (ActionResult);
```

that means your method name will be `ActionManager` but you override `GetActionResult`.

So, could your please try to rename the method name?

Comment: thanks a lot  after that i defined client and get same error 

 var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://localhost:5001");
            var client = new  ServiceHub.ServiceHubClient(channel);

            var reply = await client.ActionManagerAsync(new ActionRequest { ActionType="Test"});

Error Service is not implemented